# Yii Optimization of Semi-static site

Tags: caching, optimization, yii

I have a site that have its pages stored in Database as html strings (generated with CKEditor) to enable user to edit them with no HTML knowledge. The site also makes extensive use of images galleries (user requirement so I have no control over it) each page with its gallery. This makes the site very slow. I have read of Yii optimization in Guide and did some query caching which improved load time a bit but it is still slow.

Since it might take as long as month for page to be updated (only when things change) is there a site-wide Yii caching technique to emulate static pages until page have been changed?
I have no control over installing APC or other extensions as I am not admin.

Any optimization idea is welcomed too.

you can see a site [here](http://pec.co.tz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is hard to give you a "definitive answer" the easiest thing you could do (next to doing optimizations mentioned at [Yii's Definitive Guide: Performance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance)) is to use [page caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.page)

As you can't use APC or memcached I suggest you to use a file cache via [CFileCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileCache/) to cache the whole page. As soon as it is updated you should then invalidate the cache via a proper CacheDependency. I've used the [Flushable cache dependency extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/flushable) for invalidating a cache using CActiveRecord's afterSave hook. It is easy to implement and does the job.

EDIT: Just took a look at your site and judging from the menu you are using Bootstrap (maybe using Yii-Booster?). The site is extremely slow indeed, but that might actually be due to an extension publishing its assets on every request. I once had this exact problem with Yii-Booster publishing assets when in DEBUG mode (back then it even happened when DEBUG mode was disabled)(https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/pull/229).

Comment: Yes, I use YiiBooster. Is there an option to optimize the extension? I will check the link. And thanks for extensive information

Comment: If you are using the latest Yii_Booster version + disabling Yii's DEBUG mode (which you should do anyway in a production environment) the republishing of assets shouldn't happen.

Comment: I did mistrake, I commented the line defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true); instead of just changing it to defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',false);

Comment: Now I still need to cache images as they take time to load. Iam checking Flushable cache dependency extension

Comment: would you recommend caching output explained here http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/caching.page 
Just want to hear your opinion!

Comment: Yes, this is more or less the way I would do it (in combination with the cache dependency mentioned above). HTTP caching might be interesting as well, but use page caching first and if it is enough just leave it that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Yii HTML Cache](https://github.com/narekmarkosyan/yii-html-cache) to create full cache of your page. It generates html file in your assets and use it till lifetime ends or you clear your assets.

You just need to install extension and add few lines to `beforeAction` and `afterRender` methods of your controller.